# In graphql-yoga, how to import backtick object correctly?

Tags: typescript, express, graphql

I have graphql express app.
Right now, I would like to import the object below from schema.ts to index.ts

```
export default `{
  type Query {
    hi: String
  }  
}`
```

when I import them into the index.ts, the object changed to the one below

```
{
  type Query {
    hi: String
  }
}
```

Because of that, my app does not find the query. how can I import the object correctly?

Comment: That’s not an object, that’s a String. Do you actually want to be building a graphql schema, eg, https://www.apollographql.com/blog/graphql/how-to-use-graphql-with-javascript-graphql-js-tutorial/?

Comment: I see. but the posted link does not show the way to export the type.

Comment: `export { schema }` It’s a reference like any other.